# Using div as an input to identify words begining with #

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I am writing a code so that when a user types word beginning with `#` the word turns to red, I am using `editable div` instead of `textarea` because div allows me to change the color of certain words, the problem is that when I run my code and it turns a word to red the cursor moves to the beginning if the text in div,is it possible to get the cursor back where it was so I could type again.

Code:

```
$('#editablediv').bind('keypress', function(){
text=document.getElementById('editablediv').innerText;
$(this).html(text.replace(/#([^ ]+)/g, '<span class=tag>#$1</span>'));
});
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: Since you're replacing the entire contents of the DIV, the editor loses track of the editing position. You need to remember the position and then reset it when you're done.

Comment: I dont know how to make fiddle but I updates my code more information, also I dont understand the answer of the question that this question is a duplicate of.